# How to deploy MVVM WPf N-tier application

Tags: c#, .net, deployment, mvvm, n-tier-architecture

so , my users suddenly changed their minds and decided to go for a networked application , I have

views and viewmodels on the same project (UI) , a BLL layer dll in a ClassLibrary project and my DAL was generated using EF in another ClassLibrary project, In my development machine all these projects are on the same Solution and thus the BLL is referncing the DAL dll and the UI project(view and viewmodels) references the BLL dll ,now I want to deploy the UI project in the client machine and make it to reference the BLL dll which is located on the server where we also have the DAL dll and the database itself. the UI make a call to the BLL on the server and the BLL ask the DAL for some data, the DAL connets to the Database and get the data back, is it possible ? if yes how can I make my client to reference a dll located on another machine (the Server)

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I'm pretty sure your customer has a different understanding of a 'networked application'

Comment: yes he do , I've got to do some changes in my database as well as the code itself , but since I was already doing an MVVM n-Tier application why not benefit from that and distribute my  layers as I stated above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a WCF Service which will use your BLL and deploy WCF on a server which is accessible to your clients then consume WCF in your WPF application.

Comment: I don't want to create a new project, I'm looking to modify this existing one , specially that I know nothing about WCF services

Comment: Can't you bundle BLL and DAL with WPF executable, so each client will just connect to centralized database.

Comment: If you are referencing BLL in WPF project, how can you separate it?

Comment: I don't want to seperate it , I just want to reference it from another machine , yes I can bundle them but then I have to deploy EF for oracle in every client and new updates I have to reinstall it on every client , that what I want to avoid

Comment: Simple Webservice (.asmx), WCF Service, JSON/REST Service are the only good option to solve your problem, thats what I can think of right now.